# Precise suddenly showing blank screen on bootup

Tags: 12.04, startup

I've been using my system for quite some time now, and it's been working (more or less) fine. But today, for no apparent reason, my it suddenly stopped working.

What happens is that when I turn on the computer, Ubuntu loads until the stage where it shows the mouse pointer. Then, it just hangs there without ever getting around to showing the login screen. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed from checking your RSS feed that you have a graphics card installed in your computer. Your problem could be a caused by a failing graphics card.

Comment: Yes, it was the graphics-card all right. I figured it out soon after posting the question, but then it failed completely and I could only use the command line. And unfortunately, that doesn't let you log in to AskUbuntu. Sorry for the late reply...